# New to javascript, why won't my button work?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a quick function I wrote to check that the input supplied is equal to some pre-defined value. If it is, then it should display "Login Successful".

```js
function getUsername(){
  var username = document.getElementById("userID").nodeValue;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").nodeValue;
  if (username=="example@example.com" && password=="123"){
  alert('Login Successful');
  }   
}
```

```html
<input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" 
id="userID">

<input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" 
id="password">

<Button class="login100-form-btn" onclick="getUsername()">Login</Button>
```

Comment: `.nodeValue`? did you mean `.value`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.value` for obtaining values of `input` elements:

```js
function getUsername() {
  var username = document.getElementById("userID").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == "example@example.com" && password == "123") {
    alert('Login Successful');
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="userID">

<input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="password">

<Button class="login100-form-btn" onclick="getUsername()">Login</Button>
```